# Big O Notation Confusion (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, big-o

```
int f(const std::vector<int>& v) {      
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {                O(N)
        for (int j = v.size(); j >= 0; j -= 2) {        O(N/2)
            result += v.at(i) * j;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The inner for loop is O(N/2), however I am wondering why this is because

For example, if v.size() is 10, then

10 >= 0  ✓

8 >= 0 ✓

6 >= 0 ✓

4 >= 0  ✓

2>= 0 ✓

0 >= 0 ✓

-2 Fails

The inner for loop could be executed 6 times with an input size of 10

What am I missing?

EDIT* I understand that only highest magnitude is taken into consideration. This question was more about coming up with the original O(N/2 + 1)

Comment: The inner loop is `O(N)`. `O(N/2)` = `O(N)`. Constants aren't a contributing factor for asymptotic growth notations.

Comment: I understand this, but I am just curious as to how O(N/2) is obtained

Comment: Because it is close enough for rock and roll. It is also irrelevant. All that matters that is if you double N, you approximately double the work.

Comment: I can't resist pointing out, as an aside, that the entire calculation can be rewritten to be **O(N)** instead of **O(N^2)**.

Comment: @paddy could you elaborate

Comment: The whole inner loop is essentially a constant multiplier on `v.at(i)`

Comment: `result += N * v[i] + (N-2) * v[i] + (N-4) *v[i] + ...` is the same as using basic math to compute the total scalar `(N + N-2 + N-4 + ...)` and multiplying by `v[i]` _once_.  But this isn't what your question was about, hence I thought I'd just mention it in passing.

Comment: Yeah. What he ^ said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complexity gives you a way to assess the magnitude of time it would take an input of certain size to complete, not the accurate time it would perform with.

Therefore, when dealing with complexity, you should only consider the highest magnitude, without constant multipliers:

```
O(N/2 + 1) = O(N/2) = O(N)
```

Comment: Ah, the answer key was O(n/2) and it threw me off. I understand the highest magnitude is considered, it makes sense if it is O(N/2 + 1)

Comment: By the way, there's no point in looping over the `j==0` case anyway, since it does not affect the final result.

Comment: @Uriel I think it would still run 2 times? 3>=0 , 1>=0, -1 fails

Comment: @csguy my bad. I misinterpreted your way of considering number of times. `O(n/2 + 1)` is ok then.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, you said:

> I understand this, but I am just curious as to how O(N/2) is obtained

Take a look at the following table:

```
Size of vector     Number of time the inner loop is executed:
0                  1
1                  1
2                  2
3                  2
... 
100                51
101                51
...
2x                 x + 1
2x + 1             x + 1
```

If you take the constant `1` out of that equation, the inner loop is `O(N/2)`.